# New Project button disappeared in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

So I have been messing around trying to create an Azure Function using Visual Studio code.  Frustrated enough to start all over and now according to Microsoft, to create a new project, I have to click the Azure icon on the left hand side and click New Project:

[image]

That being said, I don't have it anymore somehow:

[image: My window]

How can I make it reappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Try to uninstall Azure Function Extension.
2.Restart Visual Studio Code.
3.Install the extension again.

Comment: Thank  you.  Last night, I figured it out, actually, it's just a whole new layout, and I was able to go to Azure Functions in Visual Studio Code, but not in the way Microsoft had indicated.  I will close this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this option was buried in the sidebar menu in vscode as pictured below. I was not able to get the icons to reappear (I'm on an Apple Silicon machine).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on how to create New Azure Function Project in Visual Studio Code appears to be out of date. I found the solution in the store page of the extension. Open the 'Azure' extension, go to Workspace, click the plus, create function. Proceed as normal as per the MS Docs. Uninstalling did not work for me as @bala suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I did not had the button to create a new local Azure function.

I uninstalled Azure function plugin and after the refresh the button appeared. When I clicked the button, it informed me that I need to have Functions plugin installed.Then I reinstalled the plug-in and the button disappeared.

Restarting and Updating VSC fixed the issue.